# SSL Cert BAD_CERT_DOMAIN Prefix?, With SAN, Local CA, Local DNS Redirect

Tags: ssl, firefox, ssl-certificate

I've got a couple of Services running internally with Certs issued by a Windows Server.
They all work with Chrome + Edge, just not with Firefox.

as an example, there's a db on the network accessed by going to https://db
It's CommonName is `{FQDN}`
It's SANs are `db`, `database`, `{IP}`, `{FQDN}`,

as I said, works fine with Chrome+Edge, but when I use Firefox I get this error:

```
https://db/

Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server’s certificate.
```

I assume it's because of the `https`? ..I've seen issues fixing `www` with `*db`, but nothing about `https` ..or maybe this is completely the wrong route, not sure.. has anyone else come across this?

any direction or advice would be appreciated!

*Note:* I can provide how I generated the certs if it's a possible settings thing, I wrote a step-by-step guide :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Per: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1323556

Firefox does not like IPs in AltSubjectNames. Removing them makes the setup work